# Looking for example of point wise convergent continuous bounded sequence of functions whose limit is neither continuous nor bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am looking for a sequence of real valued functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ with domain some subset of $\mathbb R$ such that each $f_n$ is bounded , continuous and $f_n$ converges point-wise to some function $f$ on the domain such that $f$ is neither continuous nor bounded . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

On $(0,2]$ define

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/(x+1/n) + x^n, 0< x\le 1\\ 
1/(1+1/n) + 1, 1\le x \le 2 \end{cases}$$

Each $f_n$ is bounded and continuous on $(0,2]$ and the pointwise limit is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x, 0< x < 1\\ 
2, 1\le x \le 2 \end{cases}$$

which $\to \infty$ at $0$ and is discontinuous at $1.$

Answer (score 0):

About the unboundness, take $f_n : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by

$$f_n(t) = \left\{ \begin{array} 
.t & if & t \in [0,n] \\
n-t & if & t \in [n,2n] \\
0 & & elsewhere \end{array}\right.$$

each $f_n$ is bounded and continuous, and the sequence $(f_n)$ converge pointwise to $f(t) = x$ that is unbounded.

Now about the non continuity, consider the function $g_n : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by

$$g_n(t) = \left\{ \begin{array} 
.nt & if & t \in [0,\frac{1}{n}] \\
1 & & elsewhere \end{array}\right.$$

each $g_n$ is bounded and continuous, and the sequence $(g_n)$ converge pointwise to

$$g(t) = \left\{ \begin{array} 
.0 & if & t=0 \\
1 & & elsewhere \end{array}\right.$$

and g is not continuous.

If you want both non continuity and non boundness, just take the sequence $$h_n = f_n+g_n$$